# "for about one year" or "for around one year"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, adverbs

Which of the following sentences is correct or better?

> I have been using this software for about one year.
>
> I have been using this software for around one year.

Searching in Google gives 14 million hits for "for about one year" and 1.5 million hits for "for around one year". Seems that "about" is better, but my test is not very conclusive.

Comment: Related: [When to use "around" and "about"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3862/when-to-use-around-and-about) and [What word can I say if I want to give approximate number?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22910/what-word-can-i-say-if-i-want-to-give-approximate-number/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either one is fine. There is absolutely no meaningful distinction between the two in this case.